# Export only getter or setter from a module

Tags: haskell, invariants, haskell-lens, lenses

Is there a way for me to only export specific getters xor setters from a module with a lens?

For example, let's assume a data structure that has an invariant of being always `>= 0`, being modified only by incrementing it and being created only with an initial value of `0`:

```
module Something
    ( Counter
    -- export only `count` getter
    , make
    , increment
    ) where

data Counter = Counter { _count :: Int } deriving (Eq)
makeLenses ''Positive

make :: Counter
make = Counter 0

increment :: Counter -> Counter
increment c = c ^. count %~ (+1)
```

how would I be able to only export the `count` getter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A lens isn't, in fact, "a getter and a setter", it just happens to be isomorphic to such a pair. So you can't just export one of them, rather you have to define something new and export that. Fortunately, this is extremely simple:

```
data Counter = Counter { _count' :: Int } deriving (Eq)
makeLenses ''Counter

count :: Getter Counter Int
count = count'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only generate `Getter` and `Fold` optics (as appropriate) you can use the new `generateUpdateableOptics` setting

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Lens

data Counter = Counter { _count :: Int } deriving (Eq)

let rules = set generateUpdateableOptics False lensRules in
  makeLensesWith rules ''Counter

-- Generates:
-- count :: Getter Counter Int
```